# Variable substring Edit/Replace inside a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to replace a variable's substring, previously stored on a variable inside a for loop, I tried to do it like this but it didn't work:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set checkVar=abcd
FOR %%Y IN (*.pdf) DO (  
    SET meu=%%Y
    CALL SET meuWithoutChar=!meu:%%%checkVar%%%=! 
    ECHO meuWithoutChar=!meuWithoutChar!
)
```

For example here `if %%Y==blepabcdnnnn.pdf`; I want to have `meuWithoutChar=blepnnnn.pdf` on the output
Thank you in advance

Comment: You do not need to use that many percent symbol nor do you need to use the CALL if you are trying to use delayed expansion.  The replace variable is outside the loop so you only need a single set of percent symbol. You are attempting to use delayed expansion but you have not enabled it with a `SETLOCAL` command.

Comment: While not required by syntax, proper indenting helps reading the code.

Comment: I wrote the question a little too fast, sorry 
I edited it to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are bit confused on the concept of delayed expansion and the use of CALL to get an extra phase of expansion.  Here are the examples. I am just using your single file example.  You can change it back to using the wildcard.

CALL example

```
@echo off
set checkVar=abcd
FOR %%Y IN (blepabcdnnnn.pdf) DO (  
SET "meu=%%Y"
CALL SET "meuWithoutChar=%%meu:%checkVar%=%%" 
CALL ECHO meuWithoutChar=%%meuWithoutChar%%
)
pause
```

Delayed Expansion

```
@echo off
setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
set checkVar=abcd
FOR %%Y IN (blepabcdnnnn.pdf) DO (  
SET "meu=%%Y"
SET "meuWithoutChar=!meu:%checkVar%=!" 
ECHO meuWithoutChar=!meuWithoutChar!
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you!
On my first try I tired `CALL SET meuWithoutChar=!meu:%checkVar%=!` , but it didn't work. Over the fact that the use of CALL wasn't necessary, I don't know where I messed it up. (sorry for mixing everithing up, I'm not used to code)

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement/extension to Squashmans answer.
*Only cycles through necessary files and ignores the file's extension.*

Without delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "strChr=abcd"
For %%A In ("*%strChr%*.pdf") Do (Set "objFileName=%%~nA"
    Call Set "objNewFile=%%objFileName:%strChr%=%%%%~xA"
    Call Echo %%%%objNewFile%%%%=%%objNewFile%%)
Pause
```

With full script delayed expansion, *(will have issues with filenames containing `!`'s)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "strChr=abcd"
For %%A In ("*%strChr%*.pdf") Do (Set "objFileName=%%~nA"
    Set "objNewFile=!objFileName:%strChr%=!%%~xA"
    Echo %%objNewFile%%=!objNewFile!)
Pause
```

With toggled delayed expansion, *(protects filenames containing `!`'s)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "strChr=abcd"
For %%A In ("*%strChr%*.pdf") Do (Set "objFileName=%%~nA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "objNewFile=!objFileName:%strChr%=!%%~xA"
    Echo %%objNewFile%%=!objNewFile!
    EndLocal)
Pause
```

Comment: Thank you! 
If I understood, `call` command can always be used instead of the delayed expansion and reciprocally?

Comment: @Blumer, no it cannot. Whilst it may work in the specific case above, the `Call` command is not an alternative for enabling delayed expansion, _(you can't `Call If "%%objNewFile%%"=="efgh" ...` for instance)_.